# how to do bulk indexing to elasticsearch from python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I have nearly 10K json documents and i want to push all this documents to elasticsearch by using elasticsearch bulk api from python.
I went through some docs but didn't get any solutions.

```
result=es.bulk(index="index1", doc_type="index123", body=jsonvalue)
helpers.bulk(es,doc)
```

i tried both but no result,i am getting this error

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'illegal_argument_exception', u'Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]')
```

please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer using the bulk method present in helpers module for bulk indexing. Try the following:

```
from elasticsearch import helpers
res = helpers.bulk(es, jsonvalue, chunk_size=1000, request_timeout=200)
```

Your jsonvalue needs to follow a particular format. It needs to be a list of the 10K json documents with each document having the following fields:

```
doc = {
    '_index': 'your-index',
    '_type': 'your-type',
    '_id': 'your-id',
    'field_1': 'value_1',
    ...
}
```

So your final **jsonvalue** would look something like this:

```
jsonvalue = [
    {
    '_index': 'your-index',
    '_type': 'your-type',
    '_id': 'your-id',
    'field_1': 'value_1',
    ...
},
    {
    '_index': 'your-index',
    '_type': 'your-type',
    '_id': 'your-id',
    'field_1': 'value_2',
    ...
},
    {
    '_index': 'your-index',
    '_type': 'your-type',
    '_id': 'your-id',
    'field_1': 'value_3',
    ...
}
]
```

Comment: can't i write my json documents inside  "_source": {
        }

Comment: _source convention is the way elasticsearch stores the data internally and returns it in this way. You should pass your json document at the first level in the dictionary.

Comment: sorry i am not getting you, please tell me where should i use 'doc' in helpers.bulk(), and where should i pass my json documnets?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: yeah my json value is in above format , where should i pass that value and where should i pass 'doc' in helpers.bulk()?

Comment: helpers.bulk(es, jsonvalue, chunk_size=1000, request_timeout=200). The 2nd argument should be the list of all the documents, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: so now in this helpers.bulk(es, jsonvalue, chunk_size=1000, request_timeout=200)  which argument is holding "index name,doc_type" and all

Comment: Index name and doc type are now part of each document, _index and _type hold the values for index & doc type respectively. Please read the documentation http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk here

Comment: Tried for sample data                                                                         jsonvalue = {
    '_index': 'your-index',
    '_type': 'your-type',
    '_id': 'your-id',
    'field_1':{"priority": "CRITICAL"}
}
helpers.bulk(es, jsonvalue, chunk_size=1000, request_timeout=200)           but getting  error elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'action_request_validation_exception', u'Validation Failed: 1: index is missing;2: type is missing;3: index is missing;4: type is missing;5: index is missing;6: type is missing;7: index is missing;8)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152618/discussion-between-jai-sharma-and-rcp).

Comment: from **2020** => '_index': 'your-index', '_type': 'your-type', '_id': 'your-id', 'field_1':{"priority": "CRITICAL"} } helpers.bulk(es, jsonvalue, chunk_size=1000, request_timeout=200) but getting error elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'action_request_validation_exception', u'Validation Failed: 1: index is missing;2: type is missing;3: index is missing;4: type is missing;5: index is missing;6: type is missing;7: index is missing;8)2020: this says